# Under what circumstances will SalesForce substitute an email attachment on an outgoing message?

Tags: email, attachment

I've noticed that occasionally, SalesForce will replace a file attachment I send via email with an html attachment that auto-refreshes and downloads the file via browser.

So for example, if I attach a 9 MB file called foo.zip to an email I send through SalesForce, the recipient gets an email containing foo.zip.html

Where is this set and how does SalesForce determine which attachments to substitute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's over 3mb:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm

Also an idea to increase the limit:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l5PAAAY